# 1px border showing on chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, css

On the following web page http://achi.co/about.php

Towards the bottom before the footer, there are a number of boxes, each with a number displayed inside. In google chrome the "+" and "6" have what can be described as a small 1px line on the right border.

all of these boxes are semantically identical to the other boxes which do not have this 1px line, and this issue is limited to chrome and firefox

I am unsure of why it is being rendered and how to get rid of it.

any ideas?

Comment: I don't see any reason to use percentages as your width for those boxes. I suggest you use `width: 106px;` and center it a little more.

Comment: this site is responsive - I have no option but to use percentages

Comment: I think you mean fluid, you can still have a responsive site with fixed widths.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a border. It's because the element behind (which displays on hover) is 1px wider than the one in front. You should try setting both of those elements to `width: 106px`.

In fact, if you resize your browser window to about 760px wide, you'll notice the red overhang is much greater than 1px.

Comment: The element in front is 3000px wide which is wider than any element on the whole site...

Why would the "1px border" not be consistent and show in all the boxes?

*I know it's not a border - but I'm describing it as such

Comment: No, it's not. My browser window is 1657px wide. Moving towards the element in question: html:1657px; body:1657px; .container:1657px; .row.push:1000px; .twelvecol.last:790px; .fact.twocol: 107px. Now, care to explain the downvote?

Comment: @JezenThomas: I gave the downvote for suggesting a fixed width solution to a completely fluid layout.

Comment: @randomguy Great contribution. Did you test the site at lower viewport size? The correct answer is obviously to change the structure, but do you really think that answer is within the scope of the question?

Answer (score 0):

The weird behavior of the underlying magenta-ish boxes is because of this:

> in [1140.css](http://achi.co/css/1140.css) on line 27

```
.row .twocol {
    width: 13.44%;
}
```

Changing the `width` value to `13.48%` seems to fix this issue.

About the border that becomes visible if the viewport is small enough:

If it's not intentional, an easy fix would be to change the `margin-right` here:

> in [styles.css](http://achi.co/css/styles.css) on line 452

```
.lense {
    ...
    margin-right: -15px;
    ...
}
```

To `-20px`

Comment: This isn't an universal fix, breaks down at other window sizes.

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue. There is still plenty of red showing when the viewport is less than 760px wide.